# Intel Power Management not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, power-management, intel, fan

I am new to Ubuntu. My laptop is Lenovo Z570 Intel® Core™ i3-2348M which i bought 4 year before. Still working as a hero :P

Recently i switched to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. But it ended up in burning my motherboard, battery and adapter. First i thought it was because of over voltage, but later i get to know that my power management actually not working at all. CPU FAN always runs at same speed irrespective of the CPU temperature. It causes heating up.

How can i fix this? I am not going to buy new motherboard once again!!

If i am not included much data comment what you need to know.
.
Also following are from my pwmconfig

> Found the following devices:
>
> hwmon0 is acpitz
>
> hwmon1 is coretemp
>
> hwmon2 is nouveau
>
> hwmon3/device is thinkpad
>
> Found the following PWM controls:
>
> hwmon3/device/pwm1           current value: 0
>
> /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 201: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
>   hwmon3/device/pwm1 stuck to 0
>
> Manual control mode not supported, skipping hwmon3/device/pwm1.
>
> There are no usable PWM outputs.

Comment: Have you installed any of the laptop management tools?  Either `laptop-mode-tools` or `tlp` (I prefer `tlp`) will help, but they are mutually incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first checking to see if thermald is installed. If not, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

and see if this helps.

Comment: Along with Thermald, please install TLP via its PPA https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp my Thinkpad X220 run flawless with Ubuntu 14.04.3 but do make sure you have latest BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a second-hand Thinkpad T420 and installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I am using the bios's own fan control mechanism. Applications such as Thinkfan and fancontrol are removed.

The bios's configuration for Power management offers separate settings for mains- and battery-powered use viz. either max-performance, balanced or low-power/battery. 'Balanced' makes a compromise between performance and quietness.

Set for 'max-performance' and powered from the mains-supply, running the Unixbench test and logging using Psensor (sample ever 1sec, log every 2secs) the 'highest-loading area' example in my log file was:

```
...
2963,94,0,65,0,64,0,64,0,4464,0,5,0,34,7,
2968,88,0,95,0,87,0,95,0,4051,0,89,8,34,4,
2973,94,0,97,0,89,0,97,0,3893,0,91,9,34,5,
2978,,95,0,88,0,95,0,3889,0,92,0,34,4,
...
```

The above part-result were somewhere in the '4 x pip' tests (circa 20+ minutes in). System monitor indicated 4 x 100% uP cyclic loading of ca. 15 seconds flat-out and then down for 3 - 4 secs. Room (ambient) temperature was 22C (72F).

WARNING: Thankfully Unixbench can be immediately stopped with CTRL-C. My fan/heatsink is 'clean' and I guess makes a good thermal-contact. If this was NOT so then temperatures could well rise exceedingly fast even when the fan is running flat out. Please do not underestimate dust etc. blocking air-paths and poorly fitted/contacting heatsinks (eg. following a repair, etc). When testing, watch temperatures and be ready with CTRL-C!
PS. On T420 remove screw, lift out keyboard and vacuum-clean fan etc...